# Dynaminc Postgres Function returning 1 instead of JSONB

Tags: postgresql

I have written a postgres fucntion which looks like this  Can someone suggest me on how to fix the incorrect response?

#### Brief overview

I hav two type of table. Table 1 named "company_users" which have all the users of company.

company_users have a unique key `email` and primary key `id` and another key `workspace_id`

and then I have table `users_xyz` where `xyz` would be service such as github, jira, notion etc.

users_xyz, would have `email` as unique field (nullable), `company_user_id` which is also nullable and unique and `workspace_id` which is nullable.

The idea is a service can have member outside of a company.

### What I am trying to to achieve,

i want all the users in the company (company_users) and their respective data in each of the service (users_xyz)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_users_info(_workspace_id BIGINT, services TEXT[], _id BIGINT DEFAULT NULL)
RETURNS JSONB AS $$
DECLARE
  result_array JSONB;
  table_name TEXT;
  table_join_query TEXT := '';
  join_tables TEXT := '';
  union_query TEXT := '';
  union_tables TEXT := '';
  _service_name TEXT;
BEGIN
  -- Iterate over the services and build the join and union clauses
FOREACH _service_name IN ARRAY services
  LOOP
    table_name := 'users_' || _service_name;
    table_join_query := ' LEFT JOIN ' || table_name || ' ON cu.email = ' || table_name || '.email AND cu.workspace_id = ' || table_name || '.workspace_id';
    join_tables := join_tables || table_join_query;
    union_query := ' SELECT ''' || _service_name || ''' AS service_name,  account_id, user_state FROM ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || table_name || '.email = cu.email AND ' || table_name || '.workspace_id = cu.workspace_id UNION ALL ';
    union_tables := union_tables || union_query;
  END LOOP;


  -- Remove the trailing UNION ALL from union_query
  union_query := LEFT(union_query, LENGTH(union_query) - 11);
  RAISE LOG 'Debug: union_query = %', union_query;
  -- Construct the main SQL query
  EXECUTE format('
    SELECT cu.id, cu.name, cu.email, cu.created_at, cu.active, (
      SELECT jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_build_object(
          ''service_name'', services.service_name,
          ''account_id'', services.account_id,
          ''user_state'', services.user_state
        )
      )
      FROM (
        %s
      ) AS services
    )
    FROM company_users cu %s
    WHERE cu.workspace_id = $1 AND ($2 IS NULL OR cu.id = $2) 
  ', union_query, join_tables) USING _workspace_id, _id INTO result_array;
  RAISE LOG 'Debug: result_array = %', result_array;
 RETURN result_array;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**This is returning 1 instead of following type**

```
 export interface UserData {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    userId: number;
    email: string;
    created_at: string;
    active: boolean;
    account_id: string;
    secondary_email?: string;
    services:{
          service_name: string;
          id: string;
          user_state: UserState;
        }[]

  }
```

The join and union query should ideally look like this

##### JOIN

```
LEFT JOIN users_github ug ON cu.email = ug.email AND cu.workspace_id = ug.workspace_id
LEFT JOIN users_asana ua ON cu.email = ua.email AND cu.workspace_id = ua.workspace_id
LEFT JOIN users_zoom uz ON cu.email = uz.email AND cu.workspace_id = uz.workspace_id
```

#### UNION

```
SELECT 'github' AS service_name, ug.account_id, ug.user_state FROM users_github ug WHERE ug.email = cu.email AND ug.workspace_id = cu.workspace_id
UNION ALL
SELECT 'asana' AS service_name, ua.account_id, ua.user_state FROM users_asana ua WHERE ua.email = cu.email AND ua.workspace_id = cu.workspace_id
UNION ALL
```

Comment: It would be easier to analyse if you provided a reproducible example: `create` statements for the tables involved with `insert` statements populating those with some mock records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [dynamic SQL statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) is returning 6 columns and then trying to feed all 6 into a single `jsonb` variable `result_array`. What happens is only the first column `cu.id` gets assigned and cast to the variable type, the rest of the columns get discarded. Same for rows - if you expected all rows to end up in the variable, it's actually only the first one:

> If multiple rows are returned, only the first will be assigned to the `INTO` variable(s)

Consider this example: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RoiDJZMf)

```
drop function if exists test();
create or replace function test(_workspace_id bigint, _id bigint)
returns jsonb language plpgsql as $func$
declare 
  result_array jsonb; 
  some_var int:=777;
begin 
EXECUTE format($dyn_sql$
    SELECT cu.id, cu.name, cu.email, cu.created_at, cu.active, (
      SELECT jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_build_object(
          'service_name', services.service_name,
          'account_id', services.account_id,
          'user_state', services.user_state
        )
      )
      FROM (
        values ('s1','a1','u1'),('s2','a2','u2')
      ) AS services(service_name,account_id,user_state)
    )
    FROM (values (1,'n1','e1','2023-02-02 0100'::timestamp,true),
                 (2,'n2','e2','2023-03-03 0300'::timestamp,false) )
         as cu(id,name,email,created_at,active)
  $dyn_sql$) USING _workspace_id, _id INTO result_array;
return result_array;
end $func$;
select * from test(11,22);
```

| test |
| --- |
| 1 |

It's selecting 6 columns, but feeding into a single variable, so only the first one gets assigned, rest discarded.

If you want the entire result to be one single `jsonb` fed into your output variable, you need to merge those columns into that desired `jsonb` structure:

```
create or replace function test(_workspace_id bigint, _id bigint) 
returns jsonb language plpgsql as $func$
declare  result_array jsonb; 
         some_var int:=777;
begin 
EXECUTE format($dyn_sql$
    SELECT jsonb_build_object(
                'id',cu.id,
                'name',cu.name, 
                'email',cu.email,
                'created_at',cu.created_at,
                'active',cu.active, 
                'services',(SELECT jsonb_agg( jsonb_build_object(
                              'service_name',services.service_name,
                              'account_id',services.account_id,
                              'user_state',services.user_state ) )
                            FROM (values ('s1','a1','u1'),
                                         ('s2','a2','u2') ) 
                                  AS services(service_name,
                                              account_id,
                                              user_state)
                        )
            )
    FROM (values (1,'n1','e1','2023-02-02 0100'::timestamp,true),
                 (2,'n2','e2','2023-03-03 0300'::timestamp,false) )
         as cu(id,name,email,created_at,active)
  $dyn_sql$) USING _workspace_id, _id INTO result_array;
return result_array;
end $func$;

select jsonb_pretty(test(11,22));
```

| jsonb_pretty |
| --- |
| { "id": 1, "name": "n1", "email": "e1", "active": true, "services": [ { "account_id": "a1", "user_state": "u1", "service_name": "s1" }, { "account_id": "a2", "user_state": "u2", "service_name": "s2" } ], "created_at": "2023-02-02T01:00:00" } |

Comment: Keep in mind that's just an example and while it solves your *"a `1` instead of result"* problem, I'd anticipate another surprise along the lines of *"a single record when multiple expected"*. If you planned to get and grab multiple rows resulting from that query and feed them *all* into the output variable as a single `jsonb`, you'll have to wrap that query in a `jsonb_object_agg()` or `jsonb_agg()`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FPlSJgch)